# Can't get the same result as the Delphi code, after I exclusive-OR an address of a char array in C#

Tags: c#, delphi, pointers, xor, unsafe

*Parameters: InLong = 0, Posit = 5, and from an ASCII file TmPChar{.,STX,NUL,NUL}*

**Delphi code**

```
Procedure TForm1.GetLongFromBuf(Var InLong : Longint; Posit : Integer; ZRepB : ZrepBuf);
Var
  TmpPChar     : Array[0..3] Of Char;
  PLong        : ^Longint;
  I            : Byte;
Begin
For I:= 0 To 3 Do
   TmpPChar[I] := ZRepB[Posit+I];
PLong := @TmpPChar;
InLong := PLong^;
End;
```

Outputs: TmPChar {'.', #2, #0, #0}, PLong = 13F54C, InLong = 558

**C# code**

```
unsafe static long GetLongFromBuf(long InLong, int Posit, char[] ZRepB){
 long* Plong;
 char[] TmpPChar = new char[4];
 for (byte i = 0; i < TmpPChar.Length; i++){
    TmpPChar[i] = ZRepB[(Posit-1) + (i)];
 }
 fixed(char* ch = TmpPChar){
  PLong = (long*)&ch;
  InLong ^= (long)PLong;
 }
 return InLong;
}
```

Outputs: TmPChar{'.','\u0002','\0','0'}, PLong = 0x0000000000b3cc18, InLong = 11783192

Comment: What version of Delphi? Is Char unicode (since d2009)?  WTF here: `InLong ^= (long)PLong;` ?

Comment: In addition to the questions @MBo asked, How is `ZrepBuf` defined?

Comment: Also, there is no XOR in the Delphi code.  Why are you using it in C#?  Are you confusing the dereference operator?

Comment: @MBo thank you for your immediate response. It is Delphi 5 with non Unicode d2005. By (InLong ^= (long)PLong; ) i am decrypting the value using the XOR Encryption Method, it is equivalent to InLong = InLong ^ (long)Plong; But i am not sure 100% for the fixed block if it is the correct conversion to C#.

Comment: C# `char` is 16 bit, Delphi 5 and D2005 `char` is 8 bit. Also, the Delphi code is not even close to the C# code. The C# code uses bitwise xor, the Delphi does not. It's not really our place to write the code for you. I suggest you spend more time in the debugger, and reading documentation, so that you understand clearly what the C# code actually does.

Comment: @J... ZrepBuf is a char array of 140 chars, where its char represent a byte from a FileStream Read.

Comment: @AdonisPso: The Delphi code **does not exclusive-or anything**. In Delphi, `^` dereferences a pointer, nothing else. The operator for exclusive-or is the keyword `xor`. The code simply interprets 4 bytes from the buffer ZRepB as a 32 bit Longint, nothing else. The way it is done is pretty convoluted, and could simply be done as: `InLong := PLongint(@ZRepB[Posit])^;` Like J..., I have the impression you don't *understand* the Delphi code at all.

Comment: @AdonisPso: in Delphi, the `^` operator (originally, an upward arrow) is the pointer operator, like `*` in C or C++ (or C#). So `Plong^` in Delphi does the same as `*Plong` in C: it dereferences the pointer `Plong`.

Comment: @David: indeed, as I said, a few comments further up. <g>

Comment: @David: you are the echo, I am the echo, you are the walrus, goo goo g'joob . <g>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that you are using this Delphi code without really understanding what it is doing.  From your results, we can conclude you are using a pre-unicode version of Delphi (ie: D2007 or earlier).  We can also guess that `ZrepBuf` is defining an array of bytes or [Ansi]Char.  The method, then, works as follows :

```
For I:= 0 To 3 Do
  TmpPChar[I] := ZRepB[Posit+I];  /* Copy four sequential bytes to TmpPChar array */
PLong := @TmpPChar;               /* Take a pointer to the head of the array */ 
InLong := PLong^;                 /* Dereference the pointer, interpreting as a 32-bit int */
```

This is code to convert four bytes to a 32-bit integer.  In Delphi the `LongInt` type is an alias for the 32-bit `integer` type, equivalent to the `int` type in C#, not `long`.  There is no use of the XOR operator in the Delphi code.  In `PLong^`, the `^` operator is a dereference operation.

In C# you can avoid `unsafe` code entirely and simply perform this conversion using the [`BitConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter?view=netframework-4.7.2) class:

```
 byte[] b = new byte[4] { 0x2E, 0x02, 0x00, 0x00 }; 
 int result = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);  // result == 558
```

Here I've defined the input array as a `byte[]` since a `char` in C# (and in Delphi 2009 or newer) is a 16-bit type (two bytes) for storing Unicode characters.  The data you are reading is ANSI encoded - I'm presuming you understand how to read your text file into a byte array.

Incidentally, in more modern Delphi you could also re-write the pointer code above to use the `TEncoding` class to perform this function [as described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55275823/327083) in a similar way to the `BitConverter` class in C#.

Comment: I have to change the "my code" as I have not written the code I am doing the conversion to C#. I have been misleaded with (^) symbol in Delphi. After i gave to the byte array the fours TmPChar elements I got the same value to C# as correctly @J... wrote .  
byte[] b = new byte[4] { Convert.ToByte(TmpPChar[0]), Convert.ToByte(TmpPChar[1]) , Convert.ToByte(TmpPChar[2]) , Convert.ToByte(TmpPChar[3]) };
                InLong = BitConverter.ToInt32(b, 0);

Comment: note that this assumes the operating system is big-endian.

Comment: @JessedeWit: How so? TmpPChar[0] is 0x2E, TmpPChar[1] is 0x02, rest ist 0. This is most definitely little-endian for 0x0000022E = 558. But I would never use an **array of char (TmpPChar) as intermediate**. I would use bytes directly.

Comment: @JessedeWit Windows is little-endian and this assumes that byte order, yes.  OP can trivially swap the byte order if support for other platforms is required.

Comment: Or assumes it is little-endian, my point is the operating system endianness matters. From the remarks of BitConverter.ToInt32: _The order of bytes in the array must reflect the endianness of the computer system's architecture;_

Comment: @JessedeWit very nice point but it is Little Endian and my C# code conversion refers to Little Endian also.

Comment: @AdonisPso I don't see where any C# code in the answer or comments mandates little endian

Comment: @AdonisPso Your C# code is also far more complicated than you need. The function should accept a byte array and then use `BitConverter.ToInt32(arr, index)`. All this copying to temp arrays is pointless.

Comment: @David: Both in Delphi and in C#, the entire function is rather obsolete. In Delphi, you can do: `myLongint := PLongint(@ZrepB[Posit]);`. In C# you can do `myInt32 = BitConverter(ZrepB, posit);`.

Comment: @You said the C# part. I don't see you talk about the Delphi part. I should have inserted "your" before the BitConverter part, sorry. Oh, wait... now I see you echoed my comment in the other comment section. <g>